# Search quantities on specific lines of text file and sum

Tags: unix, awk, sed, vi

I have a text file some miscellaneous data and with some money expenses.  I want to search all dollar quantities between specific lines and sum them.  Specific lines meaning search for dollar quantities between lines 6 and 8.

Here's an example of my text file:

```
Mary had a little $5.00 lamb
Bing bang bow

Blah blah blah

STARBUCKS Jan 8th, 2019 $7.00
MCDONALD'S Jan 10th, 2019 $6.00
UBER Jan 11th, 2019 $20.01
```

The expected answer is $33.01

I found that in VI I can search dollar quantities like this:

```
/$\d\{2}\|\$\d\{1}
```

I also saw in my search results that AWK can search numbers and sum them, but I couldn't figure out how to tailor those suggestions to my problem.

Comment: Are the $ quantities always the last entries? Also `between specific lines` is not very clear

Comment: Fair enough.  Between specific lines meaning search between lines X and Y for phrase 'blah'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$` as field separator. If there is a second column (`NF==2`) sum values in second column.

```
awk -F '$' 'NF==2{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file
```

Comment: This works brilliantly because awk converts strings to numbers using [`strtod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html). The function essentially ignores leading spaces, reads the next part as a number and all unrecognized characters are ignored. So if the second field reads `3456.89 cost of potatoes', the operation `sum+=$2` will convert `$2` to the numeric value 3456.89`. No extra hocuspocus to be done!

Comment: The second reason why this works is that the field separator `FS` is set to be `$`. Eventhough the `FS` is generally a regular expression and `$` explicilty indicates _end-of-record_, it holds an exception for single-lettred `FS` values. In that case `$` looses its special meaning!

Comment: You actually could remove the `NF==2` part

Comment: @Cyrus, I updated the question as per someones suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2852381: See: [How to run awk for some number of lines.?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89640/74329)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` with some pattern matching :

```
awk '$NF ~/^\$.*$/{amt+=substr($NF,2)}END{print "$" amt}' file
$33.01
```

Answer (score 0):

A very generic solution uses a regular expression with positive lookbehind:

```
grep -oP --regexp='(?<=\$)[0-9\.]*' inputFile | paste -s -d+ | bc
```

The regex `(?<=\$)[0-9\.]*` matches only sequences of digits and '.' if they are preceded by '$'

A modified solution using awk looks like this:

```
grep -oP --regexp='(?<=\$)[0-9\.]*' inputFile | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Both commands return 33.01

To limit the summation to specified lines, you can prepend `awk 'NR>5 && NR<9{print $0}'`:

```
awk 'NR>5 && NR<9{print $0}' inputFile | grep -oP --regexp='(?<=\$)[0-9\.]*' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Comment: F. Knorr, I updated the question as per someones suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2852381 I have added a solution that considers only specified lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' /\$(\S+)/ and $sum+=$1 ; END { print $sum } ' quantile.txt
38.01
```

the given input is

```
$ cat quantile.txt
Mary had a little $5.00 lamb
Bing bang bow

Blah blah blah

STARBUCKS Jan 8th, 2019 $7.00
MCDONALD'S Jan 10th, 2019 $6.00
UBER Jan 11th, 2019 $20.01
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd'

```
 perl -ne 'BEGIN{$s=0} if($.>=6) {/\$([\d.]+)/; $s+=$1} END{print "total=$s"}' d
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22739525)